# smtp error running db:migrate in rails

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I am trying to create some changes to my user model and upon running the migrations i ran into errors with sqlite saying the table already existed. I then did the following steps, rake db:drop, rake db:create, rake db:migrate. When i ran the migration it gave me the following error. I am not sure where to start looking with this one. I know it seems to be pointing me to issues with the mail but i am a bit confused with this! The model i generated was the following, rails g model purchase subscription_id:integer buyer_id:integer. Are the two issues related?

```
getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known/Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:112:in `deliver!'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:2129:in `do_delivery'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:232:in `block in deliver'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionmailer-4.1.1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:527:in `block in deliver_mail'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionmailer-4.1.1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:525:in `deliver_mail'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:232:in `deliver'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:173:in `send_devise_notification'
        /Users/em/Sincuru/new/app/models/admin_user.rb:7:in `block in <class:AdminUser>'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:440:in `instance_exec'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:440:in `block in make_lambda'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:221:in `call'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:221:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `create_record'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `create_record'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:482:in `create_or_update'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:125:in `save!'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:57:in `save!'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:273:in `block in save!'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:329:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:209:in `transaction'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:273:in `save!'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:41:in `create!'
        /Users/em/Sincuru/new/db/migrate/20140905142834_devise_create_admin_users.rb:5:in `migrate'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:752:in `migrate'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:992:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1038:in `block in ddl_transaction'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `block in transaction'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:219:in `within_new_transaction'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `transaction'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1038:in `ddl_transaction'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:991:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:953:in `block in migrate'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `each'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `migrate'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
        SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:112:in `deliver!'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:2129:in `do_delivery'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:232:in `block in deliver'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionmailer-4.1.1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:527:in `block in deliver_mail'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionmailer-4.1.1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:525:in `deliver_mail'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:232:in `deliver'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:173:in `send_devise_notification'
        /Users/em/Sincuru/new/app/models/admin_user.rb:7:in `block in <class:AdminUser>'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:440:in `instance_exec'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:440:in `block in make_lambda'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:221:in `call'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:221:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `create_record'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `create_record'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:482:in `create_or_update'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:125:in `save!'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:57:in `save!'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:273:in `block in save!'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:329:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:209:in `transaction'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:273:in `save!'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:41:in `create!'
        /Users/em/Sincuru/new/db/migrate/20140905142834_devise_create_admin_users.rb:5:in `migrate'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:752:in `migrate'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:992:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1038:in `block in ddl_transaction'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `block in transaction'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:219:in `within_new_transaction'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `transaction'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1038:in `ddl_transaction'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:991:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:953:in `block in migrate'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `each'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `migrate'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
        /Users/em/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
        Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smpt.gmail.com",
    port: "587",
    domain: "test.com",
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: 'your_email_username',
    password: 'your_email_password'
  }

  CONTACT_RECIPIENT = 'yourname@yourdomain.com'
  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  # Required for Devise gem
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }

end
```

Comment: Do you use callbacks in your models that send e-mails after save / update / create etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get an answer on this and the following resolved the problem

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  :port => 587,
  :domain => "local.drop.me:300",
  :user_name => "here_valid_email_will_come",
  :password => "here_valid_passowrd_will_come",
  :authentication => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Comment: other thing you can do is not care if doesn't deliver.   by setting `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors  = false`